# How to get number from string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
adsfsd gj3h34 sdfsdfs dfs fds 24 d[4sfsdfsd sdfwe32  [3
```

Could you please tell me how to retrieve only `24` using a regex expression from that string? I have no idea...

Other examples:

String:

```
asd3 [32/ 3vsry4 1 svsdv
```

Expected output:

```
1
```

String:

```
trolololol '3211= la4so25lr 978 cxz
```

Expected output:

```
978
```

Comment: Does the number always have spaces around it? Or could it be at the beginning or end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you're looking for a series of digits `\d+` between spaces (`\s`).

You could write: `\s\d+\s` but it would capture the spaces, and wouldn't work if the number is at the very start or end of the string.

You could also write `\b\d+\b` using the word boundary assertion (`\b`) but it wouldn't work either because some characters aren't considered part of a word (you'd match `3` in `[3` for instance).

A better approach is:

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH6lO9/1)

- `(?<!\S)` means *not preceded by a non-space*
- `(?!\S)` means *not followed by a non-space*

`\S` means *a character that's not whitespace*, `(?<!`...`)` and `(?!`...`)` are *negative lookarounds*.

Both these conditions are satisfied at the start and end of strings.